# R Heat map with only one column

Tags: r

I have a dataset that has only 1 column but more than 5000 rows.

When I try to run the heatmap(data) command, I see an error saying 'x' must have at least 2 rows and 2 columns.

Is there a way to tell the heatmap to draw a single column heatmap?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `?image` instead (no dendrogram/clustering etc.):

```
m <- matrix(rnorm(100), nrow=100, ncol=1)
image(m)
```

[image]