# I want to use heatmap in my code but i am getting error

Tags: r

```
heatmap(Web_Data$Timeinpage) 
str(Web_Data)
heat = c(t(as.matrix(Web_Data$Timeinpage[,-1])))
heatmap(heat)
```

Comment: > mode(heat)
[1] "numeric" --> the dataset i used looks numeric to me

Comment: 1) what is the error message? 2) what is the output of the `str()` call? 3) Can you provide part our data using the `dput` function?

Comment: > str(Web_Data)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 32109 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ Bounces        : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Exits          : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Continent      : chr  "OC" "N.America" "N.America" "N.America" ...
 $ Sourcegroup    : chr  "(direct)" "(direct)" "Others" "public.tableausoftware.com" ...
 $ Timeinpage     : num  18 4 35 70 81 75 186 710 712 344 ...
 $ Uniquepageviews: num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Visits         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 ...
 $ BouncesNew     : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...

Comment: heatmap(Web_Data$Timeinpage) 
Error in heatmap(Web_Data$Timeinpage) : 'x' must be a numeric matrix


I used dput but the output seems too big to copy - it contains time in seconds spent on webpage. Getting error that x must be a numeric matrix

Answer (score 0):

A few items to note here:

1) by including the `c()` operator in the `c(t(as.matrix(Web_Data$Timeinpage[,-1])))` You are creating a single vector and not a matrix. You can see this by running the following: `is.matirx(c(t(as.matrix(Web_Data$Timeinpage[,-1]))))`.  `heatmap` (I believe) is checking for a matrix because...

2) You need to provide a matrix with at least two rows and two columns for this function to work. Currently, you are only give on vector - time. You will need to provide some other feature of interest to have it work correctly, such as `Continent`.

3) If you intend to plot ONLY one field, you may consider doing as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749132/r-heat-map-with-only-one-column) and use the `image()` function. (I included an example below).

4) I find the heatmap function somewhat dated in look. You may want to consider other popular functions, such as ggplot's `geom_tile`. (see [here](https://learnr.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/ggplot2-quick-heatmap-plotting/)).

Below is an example code that should produce an output:

```
#fake data
Web_Data <- data.frame("Timeinpage" = c(123,321,432,555,332,1221,2,43,0, NA,10, 44), 
OTHER = rep(c("good", "bad",6)) )

#a matrix with TWO columns from my data frame. Notice the c() is removed and I am not transposing. Also removing the , from [,-1]
heat <-  matrix(c(Web_Data$Timeinpage[-1], Web_Data$OTHER[-1]), 2,11)

#output
heatmap(heat)

#one row
heat2 <- as.matrix(sort(Web_Data$Timeinpage[-1])) #sorting as well

#output
image(heat2)
```